# Printable text rotations in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a printable report where the column headers of a table are rotated 270 degrees, and am using the following CSS:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
-o-transform: rotate(270deg);
transform: rotate(270deg);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

It looks fine on screen across all browsers, but it doesn't print correctly.

Sadly, I need to be able to do this in IE6+, and the only solution I have found so far appears to be IE9-specific.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ewww IE6... well it might be overkill but you could try a VML/SVG solution with the help of a library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: Definitely overkill; I love Raphael, but I wouldn't be able to use it in a project like this.

Comment: Ya, I would call Raphael in this case plan Z. Are the column headers dynamic? If not you could just use an image.... other than that I'm stumped. It does seem like a lot of work to use Flash or Raphael for just getting text to rotate in IE6 but it may be the only way if the headers are dynamic.

Comment: May have to just go with the image; content is being generated through .NET MVC.